# SoftLayer access control privilege for user data

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

We are using the SL API to find out information about the user that ordered a machine.  Currently, the user/apikey we're using is only returning "username" information but we would like to get the "email" associated with the user.  What access control is needed to see this?  There is little to no documentation on this and we have tried adding various privileges but we are still not getting the "email".  We need to know which privilege enables this information to be seen.

Example command we are using to fetch user info:

```
curl https://<user>:<apikey>@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/<id>.json?objectMask=billingItem.orderItem.order.userRecord
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see the email and I have the following permissions:

- View Hardware Details
- Add New User
- Add Server
- and access to the device.

Regards

Comment: "Add New User" looks to be the privilege needed.  Thanks again Nelson.